# Project point to map with Arcpy using GPS Coordinates

Tags: arcpy, gps, point

I am trying to create a new layer with just a single point using arcpy.  All that is provided is a gps lat and long.  It seems like it should be a simple problem but I just can't get it to work.  I've determined the error is that I'm not using the correct spatial reference (the point I get right now is next to the equator/meridian) but I'm not sure how to fix that.

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = 'c:\\Scrap'
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

latitude = 41
longitude = -71

p = arcpy.Point(longitude, latitude)
pg = arcpy.PointGeometry(p)
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(pg, 'test.shp')
```

Comment: Does `oat8t7` refer to a spatial reference object? It's not clear looking at your code.

Comment: Sorry, that was supposed to be latitutde, edited to reflect that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using lat/lng you want to make sure that your [output coordinate system is set](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001w00000005000000) to something like WGS84. I assume oat8t7 is a typo and is actually referring to your 'latitude.' It could be as easy as setting your output coordinate system as such:

```
arcpy.env.workspace = 'c:\\scrap'
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
sr = arcpy.SpatialReference('WGS 1984')
arcpy.env.outputCoordinateSystem = sr

latitude = 41
longitude = -71

p = arcpy.Point(longitude, latitude)
pg = arcpy.PointGeometry(p)
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(pg, 'test.shp')
```

This puts the point just off the coast of Rhode Island!